# How to move the QTextCursor from QTextEdit to another QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qtextedit, qtextcursor

How to move the QTextCursor from QTextEdit to another QTextEdit? Here is my code:

```
self.textedit = QTextEdit(MainWindow)
self.textedit_2 = QTextEdit(MainWindow)
self.cursor = self.textedit.textCursor()
self.button.clicked.connect(self.moveCursor)

def moveCursor(self):
    self.textedit_2.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cursor is related to the focus on the widget so you need to set the focus first

```
textedit_2.setFocus()
```

Comment: Thank you Brian Tompsett you answer helped me. Therefore, to really solve my problem I added some method including your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.textedit = QTextEdit(MainWindow)
self.textedit_2 = QTextEdit(MainWindow)
self.cursor = self.textedit.textCursor()
self.button.clicked.connect(self.moveCursor)

def moveCursor(self):
    self.cursor = self.textedit_2.textCursor()
    self.textedit_2.setFocus()
    self.tetxtedit_2.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
```